# Selecting a date range in db2 SQL

Tags: sql, date, variables, db2, range

I am trying to select a date range in db2 SQL.  The date range would be current day -7 days to current day - 1 day.  I would like to select all records within that range.  I have tried to do this by declaring a variable for each date:

```
CREATE OR REPLACE VARIABLE v_date7 varchar(10)
Set v_date7= select current date - 7 days from sysibm.sysdummy1
```

This will error out because

> Keyword SET not expected

I have tried adding a ; to the end of the first line, but that then errors out because the ; is not vaild.

Comment: A date minus an interval results in a date, not a varchar. It should be `current_date`, as one word.

Answer (score 0):

Try a Recursive Common Table Expression (RCTE) like this:

```
WITH T (D) AS 
(
VALUES CURRENT DATE - 1 day
  UNION ALL
SELECT D - 1 day
FROM T
WHERE D > CURRENT DATE - 7 day
)
SELECT D
FROM T;
```

Comment: Thanks for the advice.  The project got shelved for now, so I have not had a chance to do any further work.

Answer (score 0):

To create and set a global variable in the database

```
create or replace variable sevendaysago date 
      default(current_date - 7 days)
```

Comment: Thanks for the advice.  The project got shelved for now, so I have not had a chance to do any further work.